# Excel VBA: I want to take the text in between quotation marks out of a cell.

Tags: vba, excel

so say I have a cell with the following text:

`The man "BOB" leaves his "home".`

How do I make it so that the cell just says

`The man leaves his home`

I know that there are a number of ways to do this, but none of them seem easy. I could create a do loop that examines each cell character by character and removes the quotation marks that way.

I could also create a text to columns macro, so it'd look like this after:

`The man 
Bob
leaves his 
Home`

But my issue would be how would I figure out which text that I would need to delete. I realize that my example makes no sense when the words are extracted. I'm guessing that there is a formula or something that I am forgetting here?

Comment: Why is only `bob` removed and not `home`?

Comment: You can combine `Mid()` with `Search()` to pull out the text on either side of quotations.  For multiple quotations, you may want to also use `Substitute()`.

Comment: If your sentence above is  just an example, it will be very difficult. Your code need to think BOB is The man , so bob refer to The man, then Bob need to delete.  And then what will your code do if LISA, PAIDJO, JESUS, etc?

Comment: What is the specific criteria? Is it always only the first word in quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this could be done "easily" with excel's built-in functions. However, you could achieve that by using VBA code. In a module you could write a function like this:

```
Public Function ReplaceInQuotes(ByVal str)
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    regex.Global = True
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Pattern = """.+?"""
    Dim result
    result = regex.Replace(str, "")
    regex.Pattern = "\s+"
    result = regex.Replace(result, " ")
    ReplaceInQuotes = result
End Function
```

To call the above function you can write a small sub like this:

```
Public Sub main()
    Cells(1, "B").Value = ReplaceInQuotes(Cells(1, "A").Value)
End Sub
```

So, let's say if you have your string in cell A1, then in B1 after executing the `main` sub you will have your result. The function ReplaceInQuotes works with regular expressions so you might need to manipulate it a bit to deal with some "double" spaces that might appear.

Comment: Just so others to understand, the second pattern, `regex.Pattern = "\s+"`, and the second replace, `result = regex.Replace(result, " ")`, reduce multiple consecutive whitespace characters to a single space which may or may not be desirable.